# Synonym for "bringing together for the common good"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or shorter phrase to describe "bringing together for the common good" in an easier manner.

I thought about "cohesive" but that doesn't seem to imply that things were brought together.  There must be some synonym that focuses more on that things are being brought together for a good reason or cause.

In my writing I've thought about just using the phrase "bringing together for the common good" over and over but it seems verbose.

An example of usage -

"The technology is being used to bring together people for the common good."

Comment: Could you please supply a sentence which would contain the word, as required by the site rules for single-word-requests.

Comment: (1) The requirement is to supply a sentence which would contain the word you’re looking for.  You have provided a sentence which seems to be talking about whatever it is that the question is talking about, which is not quite the same thing.  (2) More than just a sentence, your question could benefit from a clearer statement of the meaning you’re looking for — perhaps in the form of a scenario.

Comment: Ok well it looks like everyone wants to close my question anyway (4 close votes at time of writing this comment) and the comments here are saying that I'm not asking the question properly so I'll go ahead and close this question, apologies to anyone who took the time to give a good answer and it sucks to see people bringing Hitler in to the answers so sorry for spawning that behavior!

Comment: Again sorry to everyone for wasting your time and posting this here, won't happen again!  In the future I'll look for other avenues to ask questions like this.  If anyone else stumbles across this hatch job of a question, consider asking questions on a more welcoming community such as quora or by googling for synonyms of your word instead as you can probably get some quality results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unite? I think that’s a good option.
(Also yay! This is my first post)

> unite
>   verb
>   1.Come or bring together for a common purpose or action.
>  [Oxford
>   Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unite)

Comment: Welcome, I've added a dictionary definition that's relevant to this. Mostly (not always) a citation or definition is given.

Comment: Hitler united the Protestant churches into one organization led by the pro-Nazi Bishop Muller.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:
cooperation

> 1.The action or process of working together to the same end.
>  [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cooperation)

I think it's a good word because "cooperation" implies working together in achieving the best ends a group of people might want.

You might say that technically the word doesn't necessarily mean working towards a common good, for example an apocalyptic cult might cooperate in expediting the coming of doomsday, that obviously wouldn't be for the larger common good. So you'd probably want to mix it with something else:

> "Humanity in cooperation toward the summum bonum."

Or utilitarian ends, or noble causes, or whatever.

I notice that may not be much shorter than what you already have, but I can't think of a single word to mean that, other than maybe something like charity, or charitable mission.

Answer (score 0):

"The technology is being used to gather a **prosperous** society. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/prosperous)

> the condition of prospering; success    Having success; flourishing: a
>   prosperous new busines.    Well-to-do; well-off: a prosperous society